# Dynamically changing field's DisplayName affests web service

Tags: acumatica

The field in the DAC is defined like this.

```
    #region NextMonthHours
    [PXDBDecimal(2, MinValue = 0.0, MaxValue = 280.0)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Next Month Hours")]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
    public virtual Decimal? NextMonthHours { get; set; }
    public abstract class nextMonthHours : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<nextMonthHours> { }
    #endregion
```

I change the display name of the field in RowSelected event.

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<EVEPPlannedHoursDetails.nextMonthHours>(sender, nextMonth+"Hours");
```

where nextMonth is "February".

I need to add this field to Acumatica Mobile Screen. When I go to web service schema the field name is "FebruaryHours"

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FebruaryHours" type="tns:Field"/>
```

I cannot use the name "FebruaryHours" because it changes every month but I also when I use field name  NextMonthHours it is not added in the mobile screen.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few ways to workaround this depending on the use case and whether the label value is static or dynamic.

If all you want to do is to change a static label in UI without having to change the display name property you can add a separate label and merge group.

Here's an example to change `Billable` in UI without changing `DisplayName` property using that technique.

[image]

Set `SuppressLabel` property to true to hide the original label bounded to `DisplayName` on UI.

[image]

Use `ADD CONTROLS` tab to add a `Layout Rule` with `Merge` property set to true.

Use `ADD CONTROLS` tab to add a label control in the merged group.

Put the original field in the merge group so they show up together on the same line in UI.

[image]

End result, label is now a UI control and wouldn't interfere with `DisplayName` property.

[image]

Comment: I've used similar techniques for dynamic label. One possibility is to substitute the Label control by a bound text box that is styled to display as a label. To do that add another textbox and experiment with those property SuppressLabel="True" SkinID="Label" so textbox doesn't show value and only label. Then you can have two independent fields, one acts as value and the other as label. All can be dynamic.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that this DAC is used in a grid and Display Name is  a column header.

Comment: OK I see, try to add a new custom field and use TextField / ValueField properties. With these you can instruct the framework to substitute the Text/Value from another field.